# C# Regex.IsMatch returns true when it shouldn't?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm attempting to match a string that can contain any number of numeric characters or a decimal point using the following regex:

```
([0-9.])*
```

Here's some C# code to test the regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("([0-9.])*");

if (!regex.IsMatch("a"))
    throw new Exception("No match.");
```

I expect the exception to be thrown here but it isn't - am I using the Regex incorrectly or is there an error in the pattern?

EDIT: I'd also like to match a blank string.

Comment: try escaping the decimal point. I believe RegEx is understanding it to be "any character".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `*` quantifier means "match 0 or more". In your case, "a" returns 0 matches, so the regex still succeeds. You probably wanted:

```
([0-9.]+)
```

The `+` quantifier means "match 1 or more, so it fails on non-numeric inputs and returns no matches. A quick spin the [regex tester](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) shows:

```
input      result
-----      ------
[empty]    No matches
a          No matches
.          1 match: "."
20.15      1 match: "20.15"
1          1 match: "1"
1.1.1      1 match: "1.1.1"
20.        1 match: "20."
```

Looks like we have some false positives, let's revise the regex as such:

```
^([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$
```

Now we get:

```
input      result
-----      ------
[empty]    No matches
a          No matches
.          No matches
20.15      1 match: "20.15"
1          1 match: "1"
1.1.1      No matches: "1.1.1"
20.        No matches
```

Coolness.

Comment: Thanks *almost* it - thank you!  My intent with the "zero or more" was that I'd also like to accept a blank string. Is there a way to add that onto the regex you suggested?

Comment: @James Cadd: yes. `^((?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|\s*)$`. But to keep your regex simple, you should probably use `str == "" || IsMatch(...)`.

Comment: Oh, and one last thought, you should avoid regex if possible. There are little nuances you might not be able to consider in your regex, like globalization. `.` isn't a universal decimal separator, and the regex in its current form doesn't account for 1000s separators. Consider using `decimal.TryParse` if possible.

Comment: This regex will match stuff like "123XYZ". This is why you should learn Regex and NEVER trust those posted everywhere (many are completely wrong).

Answer (score 12):

```
Regex.IsMatch("a", "([0-9.])*") // true
```

This is because *the group can match **ZERO** or more times.*

```
Regex.IsMatch("a", "([0-9.])+") // false
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. As Juliet pointed out, in the character class the . is treated as a literal

Answer (score 9):

You should use + instead of *

```
Regex reg = new Regex("([0-9.])+");
```

This should work fine.

When you use * any string can match this pattern in your case.